# Best way to update application over internet?

Tags: .net, deployment, auto-update

What is the best way to push out an update of a desktop .NET application over the internet?

Do you need to have a service running on a client's machine?

If the existing version of the app needs to be uninstalled first, how is this achieved via an auto-update?

Would it be easy to do this in-house?

Comment: Here is a similar discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395609/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-update-a-windows-application/7396926#7396926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickOnce does all of this for you automatically.

Comment: Yes. you need just a basic web server.