# Need help in application update

Tags: c#, .net, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

I am developing an application in SQL Server using C#.

My database version is SQL Server 2005 Express edition, and .Net framework 2.0.

I want to make an updatable application.

e.g. whenever I do some changes in my application, then it should be available to update in all locations (like update in Mozilla Firefox).

But I also want that if I change some columns/stored procedures of the database, then those changes should be also updatable.

Please guide me how can I make that kind of setup.

Comment: what does Firefox have to do with this?

Comment: @DJ KRAZE: i have tried to make normal setup application only...i am begginer for deployment jobs...

Comment: @ErOx: i gave FIrefox just for an example which kind of update i want.

Comment: how far have you gotten with the normal setup application...?

Comment: Let me rephrase: What kind of application are you building? How does updating your application affect Firefox? Firefox is just a web browser, and has nothing to do with the .NET Framework. You see where I'm going with this?

Comment: No..i think there is misunderstanding...I am developing simple windows  application in c#.net..but i want my application updatable.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE:basic like installation process completes only..I havent gone with updates..

Comment: Check into a webservice or a windows service and make sure that you are checking versioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to decide on a setup tool which will create an EXE or MSI installer for your application. Perhaps this list will help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

After that, you can integrate an updater application into that installer. Here is a post with more details: [What is the best way to auto update a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395609/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-update-a-windows-application/7396926#7396926)

An installer takes care of the distribution and the updater takes care of your application updates.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any server or network share where you can distribute your application from? 
If so, then you should take a look at ClickOnce which is available in any version of visual studio. it will automatically update the client each time you publish a new version. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

As for the SQL updates, I'm not sure what you're asking for? if you use one database for many clients, then the only thing you will have to update is the client code which works with the database. in which case you will do the same thing as with any client update.

If you're having multiple instances of the database, you'll have to update each of them manually. You'll really want to keep track of each change you've made or use a comparsion tool for that. I'm using Red Gate SQL Compare, but I assume that there are also free tools.

Comment: ClickOnce is definitely one of the best options.