# Access is denied (Running a .bat file)

Tags: c#

This is my code to build up a .bat file and run it.

```
StringBuilder Batch = new StringBuilder();
Batch.AppendLine("@echo off");
Batch.AppendLine("taskkill /IM " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe /F");
Batch.AppendLine("ping localhost > nul");
Batch.AppendLine("del /f " +  (char)34 + Application.ExecutablePath + (char)34);
Batch.AppendLine("ren " + (char)34 + Application.StartupPath + @"\update.exe" + (char)34 + " " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
Batch.AppendLine((char)34 + Application.ExecutablePath + (char)34);
Batch.AppendLine("del %0");

File.WriteAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\update.bat", Batch.ToString(), Encoding.Default);
        Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + @"\update.bat");
```

However, I get access is denied, I have to run it as a admin, how can I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to delete your own executable file? No wonder you get an access denied.

Comment: @Steve It's an auto update software. I download a file called update.exe, which is the new updated software, I kill my current, rename update.exe to my app name, and run it again. And no, thats' not why I'm getting access is denied.

Comment: If the application is on Program Files that's why you need the Admin privileges.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elevating process privilege programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but I think you are not approaching it from the best direction.  Instead see this question that provides a very robust answer for what you are actually trying to do: [what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-update-a-windows-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395609/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-update-a-windows-application)

TL;DR If your original installation is "All users" then you will have problems with having to manually elevate permissions.  Is the installation is "Per user" then this simplifies the permissions issue.